# Toyota Celica ST185 problem, doesn't start

Tags: electrical, toyota, fuse, relay, celica

Hello i have a problem i own a Toyota Celica ST185 Carlos Sainz Limited Edition. (btw. English is not my national language so sorry for eventual errors).

The problem is that car has problems with start. It starts whenewer it wants. Here's a presentation video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lakHh5TiHa4&feature=youtu.be
As u can see there is a Check Engine light. And car starts, i give a little gas and it stalled(stopped working). When i tried to launch it again there is no Check Engine light. And Car won't start.

No Check Engine light ? Then happens this: https://youtu.be/rF-MahNAhIM

If i will wait a bit(5minutes/1hour). Check Engine light appears and car starts normally. Then after random amount of time car stalls, and everything repeats. Or i can just launch it, then turn the car off try to launch it again and it won't launch(it just happens randomly)

When Check Engine light is ON it launches without any problems. Car was in the mechanic but he said that he doesn't know how to repair this, he replaced the fuses/EFI Relay. I don't know if i need to search for a better mechanic or u guys can help me solve this problem. Any suggestions what should i do ?

Comment: Have you had the codes read from the computer? This is going to be a huge part of helping you get this diagnosed.

Comment: Well last time i tried but Check Engine Light wasn't working. So i will try it tomorrow (1AM here). I will try to check them.

Also what i readed in internet is this:
When you turn the ignition ON before starting the car, the "Check engine" light is supposed to come on indicating that the engine computer  is powered on. If the "Check engine" light does not come with the ignition ON, it's possible that there is no power coming to the engine computer (e.g., due to a broken wire, faulty main relay, burnt fuse, etc.) or that there is a problem with the engine computer itself.

Comment: ECUs can fail but it's pretty rare. More likely would be a problem with the EFI relay or wiring.

Comment: Im not in the house so i can't check Codes from Computer. But what about Crank Shaft position sensor ? I think it could be it.

Comment: I checked Error Codes -> There are no error codes.